# No module named 'model_utils'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-model-utils

I'm using Python 3.4.3 and django 1.9.8.

In my models.py, I have

> from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

But this error occurs:

> ImportError: No module named 'model_utils'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to install django-model-utils:

```
pip install django-model-utils
```

([documentation](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html))